# JSF El expression remove uncessary comma

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jstl

In PrimeFaces 5.1 I show dataTable student subject show with command

```
<p:dataTable id="student" var="stud" value="#{stud.details}">                 
    <p:column headerText="studentName">
        ....
    </p:column>  
    <p:column headerText="subject">
        <c:forEach begin="1" items="#{stud.typeNameList}" varStatus="selectedSTypeIndex" var="text">
            <ui:fragment rendered="${dept.sstTypeSelected[selectedTypeIndex.index] eq true}">
                <h:outputLabel value=","/>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{text}"/>
            </ui:fragment>
        </c:forEach>
    </p:column>
</p:daTable>
```

**Example:**

```
studentName                subject
Senthil                    ,Tamil,English,Maths,Science
```

My doubt is How to remove comma in before Tamil subject using JSF or any other way?

Comment: <c:if> selectedSTypeIndex.index == 1 (or 0, don't remember) then don't show `<h:outputLabel value=","/>`

Answer (score 0):

Use `<c:choose>` to make `if elseif else ..` conditions ,
Updated code here :

```
<p:dataTable id="student" var="stud" value="#stud.details}">                
    <p:column headerText="studentName">
       ....
    </p:column> 
    <p:column headerText="subject">
        <c:forEach begin="1" items="#{stud.typeNameList}" arStatus="selectedSTypeIndex" var="text">
            <ui:fragment rendered="${dept.sstTypeSelected[selectedTypeIndex.index] eq true}">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${selectedSTypeIndex.first}">
                        <!--if first element, do nothing -->
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        <c:choose>
                            <c:when test="${dept.sstTypeSelected[selectedTypeIndex.index-1] eq false}">
                                <!--if last elemnt wasn't rendererd so do nothing -->
                            </c:when>
                            <c:otherwise>
                                <h:outputLabel value=","/>
                            </c:otherwise>
                        </c:choose>
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <h:outputLabel value="#{text}"/>
            </ui:fragment>
        </c:forEach>
     </p:column>
</p:daTable>
```

Comment: In above ,Tamil,English,Maths to not allow comma(,) is work fine.But some student have not Tamil subject I set false for Tamil that time english subject left have a comma becuase I use rendered="${dept.sstTypeSelected[selectedTypeIndex.index] eq true} show the department subject

Comment: I dont understand , you mean that when student doesn't have Tamil subject the comma is present at the begining of subjects ?

Comment: @prem I changed the code , If I had understood , it may work now !